# Install PHP Mcrypt Extension on Redhat 7.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, redhat, mcrypt

I have tried to install php mcrypt extension on redhat 7.4 using this command

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

The following errors occured.

```
No package php-mcrypt available
```

server info
      Redhat 7.4,
      php version (5.4.16),
      Laravel 5.0

Can you help me how to install this extension?

Comment: either try PECL or PEAR, php-mcrypt is removed in the newer PHP versions (7.2) due to insecurities, so it might have been removed from the YUM repo

Comment: If you are going to make your application futureproof (and you should) then do not use mcrypt as it is already removed from php 7.2 so when you will be forced to use newer version of php your application would become useless.

Comment: PHP mcrypt is a non-compatible unsupported POS and was removed from PHP because it was so bad it should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `php-mcrypt` is part of EPEL (the officially unsupported set of packages maintained in Fedora branches).  See these instructions for enabling EPEL:

- [EPEL—How can I use these extra packages?](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)